# How do governments deflect risk through greater volatility in the housing market?

Tags: risk, housing

Source: p 123 of 296, *Understanding Housing Policy*, by Brian Lund

> Although
>   housing immobility limits the impact of globalisation, its influence on financial and labour markets
>   magnifies regional and local variations in economic conditions within countries through internal and
>   international migration. This may have prompted a more ‘selective’ response from national
>   governments. **Globalisation also magnifies ‘risk’ and prompts governments to deflect this ‘risk’
>   onto homeowners in the context of greater volatility in the housing market.**

Please explain the bold, which suggests that governments want greater volatility.